# How can I use SNMP4J with Java to run snmpwalk with the -Ox parameter to force raw values?

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I have found with some devices (mainly cisco) that they sometimes return some interesting values when running an snmpwalk. I have found specifically that they can change a HEX value to ASCII.

I'm able to pull back the raw values by using the following cmd passing through **-Ox** as a parameter:
`snmpwalk -Os **-Ox** -c <community> -v 2c <ip_address> <OID>= Hex-STRING: <result_as_hex>`

**^^^I would like to do that with snmp4j if possible.**

The following cmd results in the same as the java code using snmp4j:
`snmpwalk -Os -c <community> -v 2c <ip_address> <OID> = STRING: <result_as_ASCII_value>`

Many thanks in advance!
J

I get the same response when I try to use snmp4j even though I am trying to get the VariableBinding.toValueString:

```
public Map<String, String> doWalk(String tableOid, Target target) throws IOException {
        log.info("doWalk({}, {})", tableOid, target);
        Map<String, String> result = new TreeMap<>();
        TransportMapping<? extends Address> transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        
        log.info(transport.getListenAddress().toString());
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
        
        transport.listen();
        
        TreeUtils treeUtils = new TreeUtils(snmp, new DefaultPDUFactory());
        List<TreeEvent> events = treeUtils.getSubtree(target, new OID(tableOid));
        
        if (events == null || events.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Error: Unable to read table...");
            return result;
        }

        log.info("event size is {}", events.size());
        for (TreeEvent event : events) {
            if (event == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (event.isError()) {
                log.info("Error: table OID [{}] {}", tableOid, event.getErrorMessage());
                continue;
            }
            
            VariableBinding[] varBindings = event.getVariableBindings();
            if (varBindings == null || varBindings.length == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (VariableBinding varBinding : varBindings) {
                if (varBinding == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                result.put("." + varBinding.getOid().toString(), varBinding.toValueString());
            }
        }
        snmp.close();

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Ox` flag that you are asking about doesn't affect the SNMP transaction, only the interpretation of the received data. In short, instead of using `varBinding.toValueString()`, you want to be using `OctetString.toHexString()`. Based on the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.snmp4j/snmp4j/2.8.2/org/snmp4j/smi/VariableBinding.html), it looks like you can extract the value as a `Variable`, and then cast it to an `OctetString`. Here's an example:

```
Variable value = varBinding.getVariable();
if (!value.getSyntaxString().equals("OCTET_STRING")) {
    // Throw an exception or something
}

OctetString octet_string = (OctetString) value;
String hex = octet_string.toHexString();
```

Comment: Nice one! I implemented your suggestion and it's working like a charm  Thank you for your help 